# Trigger `socket.io` event from server(`node.js`), not from client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I am trying to make a game server with `node.js`, `socket.io`.

The basic idea likes below.

- Initialize `socket.io` instance when the server starts
- Store instance in global scope, so controllers can access it
- When API calls, we trigger some `socket.io` event in the controller or some other points

Here is the implementation I made ...

First, in `server.js` - entry point

```
let GlobalVars = require('./state/GlobalVars');
const apiRouters = require('./router');

...

app.use('/api', apiRouters);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/test/simpleClient.html`)
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
let socketIOInstance = socketIO(httpServer);
socketIOInstance.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('SOCKET.IO A USER CONNECTED');
    socket.on('create', (data) => {
        console.log('SOCKET.IO create called', socket);
        socket.join(data.room);
        socketIOInstance.emit('message', 'New people joined');
    });
    socket.on('join', (data) => {
        console.log('SOCKET.IO join called', data);
    })
    socket.emit('message', 'Hi');
});
GlobalVars.socketIO = socketIOInstance; 
// Add to global, so the controllers can manage own actions like create, join ...
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server Listening on the port ${port}`);
})
...
```

When I access from a client, I am able to see `SOCKET.IO A USER CONNECTED` and `Hi` in the browser console.

Second, In api controller.

```
let GlobalVars = require('../state/GlobalVars');
...

router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  console.log('GenerateGameSokect');
  let game = new Game();
  let gameId = game.gameId;
  // console.log('Global vars ', GlobalVars.socketIO);
  GlobalVars.socketIO.emit('create', {
    room: gameId
  });
  res.json({
    result : 'SUCCESS',
    game : game
  })
});
```

I imported `GlobalVars` which contains socketIO instance. So what I expected was, socket `create` event triggered from the statement `GlobalVars.socketIO.emit('create', Object)` but could not find message in the server logs.

I got no clue what I was missing.

The final form I pursue is something like...

- When user call create API, I creates socket connection and room
- API will called in HTTP protocol, but in the API, the server publishes some events. - pubsub like.

Thanks for reading my questions b. [Here is full source code till now(bitbucket public)](https://bitbucket.org/juneyoung/simplepubsub/src)

================== EDIT ====================

I got understood (maybe...)

The user-flow I wanted was ...

1. The client call API
2. (In the server) Checking validation in API and if valid emit to `socket.io`
3. If event accepted send new status to all clients

However, creating `socket.io` connection in the server looks strange for me, the solution is up to the client.

New user-flow I will change

1. The client call a validation API
2. If return is valid, the client emit socket.io event. This time server only do validation, not emit socket.io
3. In socket event, send new status to all other users

================== EDIT #2 ====================

This is a kind of conclusion. It looks I just misunderstanding the concept of socket communication. Like answer and replies say, `Socket` and `HTTP` are totally different channels, there is no way to connect both. (At least, without open new connection from http server to socket)

If this is wrong, you could add reply, Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve: at server start, you tell socket.IO that when a socket is requested (`'connection'` event on the instance), you bind listeners to the events _of the socket being created_ (the socket, **not** the global manager). Then in your API fires a `'create'` event _on the global manager_ (**not** a socket). Would you happen to be trying to add potatoes and tomatoes? ;)

Comment: @StockOverflaw I understand that I have skipped the `connection` event when I call that in API controller. However, I do not understand fire create on the global manager part. My thought was I could fire `create` event via global manager since I stored initialized socket.io instance in `server.js`. Please some extra explanations to help me. thanks

Comment: The ultimate thing that I am trying to achieve is fire `create` event in the server method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand you. Or at least I think!

Let's put it this way: there are two (asymetric) sides on a socket, server and client. What I called, respectively, "global manager" and "socket" in my comment to your post.

```
const server = require('socket.io')(yourHttpServer);
// client is installed as well when `npm i socket.io`
const client = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:' + yourServerPort);

// `socket` is the server side of the socket
server.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // this will be triggered by client sides emitting 'create'
  socket.on('create', (data) => {
    console.log('a client socket just fired a "create" event!');
  });
});

// this will be triggered by server side emitting 'create'
client.on('create', (data) => {
  server.emit('create', {content: 'this will result in an infinite loop of "create" events!'});
});
```

In your `/create` route, when you `GlobalVars.socketIO.emit('create', ...)`, the server-side socket handler isn't triggered, however if you have clients connected through a browser (or, like I showed above, if you connect a client socket directly from the server) then these will trigger their `'create'` listener, if any.

Hope this helps you get on the right tracks!

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great effort to understand my goal. It is really close now. Lets say what if the client only listen `message` - which only receives, not emit at all - event, and instead of calling `emit` function of the socket, the client all a restful API to the server. => to the next comment

Comment: When the server controller receives the API call, is it possible to emit a event to the server side socket (In a server-client separated model)? <= It was the basic logic I am trying to implement. Thanks it would be wonderful if you give me a little more tuition:-)

Comment: If you already have a socket, why don't you use it? Besides, since socket and HTTP are viewed as different channels, there's no (easy) way for the API call to trigger the socket listener _that requires the socket reference_ (since you're doing a `socket.join`: which socket would that be, when there is no link between `GET /create` and the sockets' `create` event?)

Comment: I want to use HTTP since there will be some heavy logics for validations and I do not want to write code down inside of the socket events(want to keep it light and simple). However, just like you mentioned `HTTP` and `socket` are totally different channels so it looks not available.
Guess now I got the concept of the socket communication, thanks :-)

Comment: Cheers ;) Just a point though: your `/create` endpoint is defined by a function, the same way your `'create'` event is. So keeping it light is only about how the code is organized: `socket.on('create', require('./socket-create-handler'))` keeps it a one-liner and that dependency can have as much code as needed. In both cases anyway (socket/API), the client sends something and the server does something about it. In a socket however, a fired event does not wait for a response like `res.json`. Lighter and simpler, to me!