# How to call a socket.on() from a separated file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to call a socket.on() event from an external .js file and I can't figure out what I'm missing...
I'm using NodeJS with ExpressJS.Below are the files:

app.js(the server file)

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();
  const http = require('http').Server(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(http);
  ....
  //Socket Io functions
  const ioObj = require( './library/io.js')(app, express, io);
  // This route will be used to print the type of HTTP request the particular Route is referring to
  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("/" + req.method);
  next();
  });
  ....
```

/library/io.js (sockets file)

```
  module.exports = function(app, express, io){
     io.on('connection', async function(socket) {

  socket.on('refreshPage', function(){
    console.log("page should now be refreshed !!");
  socket.emit("refreshPageNow");
  });

  ....

 });

 }
```

What I'm trying to do is to call/access the refreshPage event from /library/io.js so I can send further a "refresh webpage" signal.
I tried to do something like :

```
 io.sockets.emit("refreshPage");
```

and

```
 ioObj.sockets.emit("refreshPage");
```

But didn't work...

Comment: This code seems legit; i.e. if it doesn't work in this external file, then IMHO it mustn't work either if you put `io`-related code in the main file. So next question is: how do you connect and send `refreshPage` from the client?

Comment: I add the socket on the webpage( `var socket = io();` ) and use the `socket.on();`
The thing is I don't send the `refreshPage` from the client,I send it from a data event that is located into a `router.post();`
The data event isn't called just once,it's called for every step of a `for` statement,would that be the problem?
So,I call the `refreshPage` from the router.post() from the server file and in the `refreshPage` I emit the `refreshPageNow`

Comment: I suspect you don't `connect` from the client side, and more importantly that you are trying to emit a client event from the server using `socket.io` package instead of `socket.io-client` package. Maybe having a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511685) will help.

Comment: I used the same methodology and it was working,the only difference was the rest of the sockets are called directly from the webpage without any nodejs things.
This one is a little bit different e.g I have to use nodejs
I don't know...the problem would be between the `io.sockets.emit("refreshPage");` and `socket.on('refreshPage', function(){...`
I tested it with some console logs,I get the console where I call the refreshPage in node but I don't get the console from the `socket.on`

Comment: This is the difference I was thinking of when talking about `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` packages. Emitting an event from `socket.io` instance won't be caught by itself. You need to emit the event from `socket.io-client` instance (which is installed when you install `socket.io`). Read the thread I linked earlier.

Comment: Okay good sir,
Thank you very much!
I'll read that documentation